# Get single row from array on ref document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this models (working with mongoose):

```
var StudentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    address: String,
    phones: [{
        name: String,
        address: String
    }]
});

var subjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    students: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Student' 
    }]
});
```

And I would like to be able to get ONE specific student details given a subject. I have tried this:

```
router.get('/:id/students/:idstudent', function(req, res, next) {
    Subject.findById(req.params.id)
        .where('students', {
            $elemMatch: {
                $eq: req.params.idstudent 
            }
        })
        .exec(function (err, post) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            res.json(post.students);
        });
});
```

But even when this print the student that I am looking for, also print all other students that are with him in the same subject. I would like to be able to get only the details from the studentId given.

Comment: Have you tried `findOneById`? http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/1.0/html/94930607-3e59-4801-b525-a8cf6c9afb99.htm

Comment: The thing is not find on the Subject collection, but in the "join" (populate) of Student. I one to find one specific student from the subject collection (which have an array of students).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`where`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-where) takes `$elemMatch` query,
Use [`select`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) to specify `$elemMatch` projection.

```
router.get('/:id/students/:idstudent', function(req, res, next) {
    Subject.findById(req.params.id)
     .select({'students': {$elemMatch: {$eq: req.params.idstudent}}}        
     .populate('students')         
     .exec(function (err, post) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(post.students);
    });
});
```

Comment: This give me this error "Invalid select: select only takes 1 argument". I'm new on this, but I'll check how to make this suggestion work. Thanks.

Comment: Np. Sorry try `.select({students: { $elemMatch: req.params.idstudent }})` You will need to use populate after you have the matching ref.

Comment: That last one give me ```elemMatch: Invalid argument, object required.```

Comment: You may have copied it too soon. I have updated the answer. Please try again.

Comment: I manage to make it work with this: ```router.get('/:id/students/:idstudent', function(req, res, next) {
    Subject.findById(req.params.id)
    .select({students: {$elemMatch: {_id: req.params.idstudent}}})
    .populate('students')         
     .exec(function (err, post) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(post.students);
    });
});``` but it give me an empty array.

Comment: students is list of id refs. So you don't need _id reference inside elemmatch. Try without the _id reference. See if it helps.

Comment: Like you suggest give me the same error of "object required", but like this worked: ```.select({'students': {$elemMatch: {$eq: req.params.idstudent}}})```. Thanks for point me in the rigth direction.

Comment: Do you think that would be a good idea if you edit your answer with the piece of code that worked for me to accept it?

Comment: Great. Updated answer.